# Store dynamically created spinner's (created using layout inflator) value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

My app users can create dynamic spinner and add items to it on click of button. Spinner is created using layout inflater. 
Example :

1. User creates 2 spinner dynamically.
2. gives input for 1st spinner - male , female
3. gives input for 2nd spinner - apple , ball , cat.

Now I want get the data separate for each spinner and save it in firebase realtime database like.

```
  (root)Dynamic->
            spinner 1 ->
                       -Male
                       -female

            spinner 2 ->
                       -apple
                       -ball
                       -cat
```

by using which method i can achieve this. i don't need the complete code just guide me which method to be used for it.

App Image : -

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Tuz.jpg)
[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW8eW.jpg)

Comment: You can try this, Construct an array of objects lets say UserDefineView class which can be container for spinner label, it's values and other properties and save it to firebase as array.

Comment: Can you explain it more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have UserDefinedView class

```
class UserDefinedView {
  String label;
  String values[];
  int id;
   /*Other properties like viewType = [Spinner,EditText..]*/
}
```

Now create a list, where you can push user define views

```
ArrayList<UserDefinedView> userDefinedViews = new ArrayList<>();

UserDefinedView mUserObject = new UserDefinedView(/*label*/,/*Values*/,...);

userDefinedViews.push(mUserObject);
```

Now you can easily store array into firebase